# I want to display image filename on image during animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uilabel

I'm new to iPhone application developing.
I created frame by frame animation which display all images from folder dynamically.
But i want to display image filename as well for particular image when it is display on screen to UILabel.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799535/ios-objective-c-problem-with-adding-different-uilabel-to-each-cell-in-uitablevi for tips

Comment: also look at this http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Thank a lot Rachel Gallen..  Can i got solution without using UITableView.

Comment: no problem happy to help :) don't know about your query. will have a look later. in work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also faced this situation. In xcode to show image you have using image name, that is a reference for the image only, the name will not stored in any where. I think you have all of your image names in array. For showing that names with particular image, just load image in array index order, & set the label.text as image name at particular index. Using this way i had cleared my situation.

Comment: I also tried it. But it displayed only last filename from array of images on all images during animation. Can you help me by providing that much of code.